# How to determine if ios user is signed in to twitter?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I want to determine it a user is signed on to twitter, so I can prompt them to post a tweet but only if they are set up with ios and twitter. Also, is there a way to set up the twitter screen with a default tweet?

Comment: when you present a `TWTweetComposeViewController` it already checks if user is logged in to twitter if not goes to settings screen with `IOS 5 and later versions`  when you use `Twitter.framework`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment if you are using IOS 5 or later versions just add `Twitter.framework` to your projects

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>

//post tweets
- (IBAction)postTapped:(id)sender{

    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@" #hashtag"];


        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {

        TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        //hide the tweet screen
        viewController.view.hidden = YES;

        //fire tweetComposeView to show "No Twitter Accounts" alert view on iOS5.1
        viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }
        };
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

        //hide the keyboard
        [viewController.view endEditing:YES];
    }


}
```

Comment: [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet] is returning true even though I have deleted my twitter account from settings.

Answer (score 5):

For iOS 5.x, you can check if the user is signed in to twitter using:

```
[TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]
```

As for presenting a tweet screen with default message, you can do something like:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[tweetSheet setInitialText:defaultMsg];
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

You can refer [this tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5&q=&esrc=s&ei=R14eUeOjKcOGrAefmYH4BA&usg=AFQjCNEswAPlSErP2wNlAEpq-pu4hspV8w) for more.

**EDIT:** For `iOS 6.0` and above, use:

```
// requires "Social.framework"
[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]
```

So, an example usage could be:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
        controller.completionHandler = myBlock;
        [controller setInitialText:@"#myHashTag"];
        [controller addImage:myImage];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
    else
    { /* Show error alert, etc*/ }
```

[Further reading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/isAvailableForServiceType%3a)

Comment: Is there something similar for Facebook?

Comment: I'm aware of how to do it on the latest FB SDK: `FBSession.activeSession.isOpen`. I haven't worked on older versions, so I can't say how it was done then.

Comment: [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet] is returning true eventhough I have deleted my twitter account from settings.

Comment: Edited answer! Use `isAvailableForServiceType`